# How to add to a list with a where condition based on mode selected?

Tags: c#, list

There are 3 modes that could be selected, it could either be `FreeAccount`, `BasicAccount`, or `PremiumAccount`.

In the `GetUsers()` method, I am going through a for loop that gets the list from a text file, but I should only be able to add where the `Account.Type` matches the `mode` selected that is a type of a string.

The reason why I want to this is because the `AccountNumber` and other properties still get added to the list, which is what I am trying to fix.

I tried to come up with a linq query as shown, but this is not adding anything to a list. I also have `BasicAccountTestRepository.cs`, `FreeAccountTestRepository.cs`, `PremiumAccountTestRepository.cs`, that has a `private static Account` with the four properties.

I was planning to either call it or somehow be able to add it to the current list, but this seems beyond for what I am asking for right now. I would like to fix this issue first before heading towards that direction.

**FileAccountRepository.cs**

```
public List<Account> accounts = new List<Account>();

    public FileAccountRepository(string mode)
    {
        GetUsers(mode);
    }

public void GetUsers(string mode) {
            string path = @".\Accounts.txt";
            string[] rows = File.ReadAllLines(path);            

            for (int i = 1; i < rows.Length; i++)
            {
                string[] columns = rows[i].Split(',');

                Account _account = new Account();
                _account.AccountNumber = columns[0];
                _account.Name = columns[1];
                _account.Balance = Decimal.Parse(columns[2]);
                if (columns[3] == "F" && mode == "FreeTest")
                {
                    _account.Type = AccountType.Free;
                    //new FreeAccountTestRepository();
                }
                else if (columns[3] == "B" && mode == "BasicTest")
                {
                    _account.Type = AccountType.Basic;
                    //new BasicAccountTestRepository();
                }
                else if (columns[3] == "P" && mode == "PremiumTest")
                {
                    _account.Type = AccountType.Premium;
                    //new PremiumAccountTestRepository();
                }

                var listModeQuery = accounts.Where(x => x.Type == _account.Type)
                    .Select(s => new Account
                    {
                        AccountNumber = s.AccountNumber,
                        Name = s.Name,
                        Balance = s.Balance,
                        Type = s.Type
                    }).ToList();

                //accounts.Add(_account);
            }    

public Account LoadAccount(string AccountNumber)
    {
        return accounts.FirstOrDefault(x => x.AccountNumber == AccountNumber);
    }

    public void SaveAccount(Account account)
    {
        //newaccount = account;
    }
```

**Accounts.txt**

```
AccountNumber,Name,Balance,Type
10001,Free Account,100,F
20002,Basic Account,500,B
30003,Premium Account,1000,P
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could filter the data read from the File before adding them to the list.

```
var dictionaryOfModes = new Dictionary<string,string>
{
    ["FreeTest"] = "F",
    ["Premium"] = "P",
    ["BasicTest"] = "B"
};
var lines = File.ReadAllLines(filePath);
var listOfAccounts = new List<Account>();
foreach(var line in lines.Skip(1))
{
    string[] columns = line.Split(',');

    if(columns[3] == dictionaryOfModes[mode])
    {

       Account _account = new Account();
       _account.AccountNumber = columns[0];
       _account.Name = columns[1];
       _account.Balance = Decimal.Parse(columns[2]);
       switch (columns[3])
       {
          case "F":
              _account.Mode = AccountType.Free;
              break;
          case "B":
              _account.Mode = AccountType.Basic;
              break;
          case "P":
              _account.Mode = AccountType.Premium;
              break;
        }
      listOfAccounts.Add(_account);
    }
}
```